# Hide and Show inputField Based upon Radio Button

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a small problem with a validation here

```
  <script>
    function myFunction(V) {
        var inputcpf = document.getElementById("CPF");
        var inputcnpj = document.getElementById("CNPJ");

        if(V.Value =='CPF'){
            inputcpf.style.display='block';
            inputcpf.required=True;
            inputcnpj.style.display='none';
            inputcnpj.removeattribute("required");
        }else{
            inputcnpj.style.display='block';
            inputcnpj.required=True;
            inputcpf.style.display='none';
            inputcpf.removeattribute("required");                

        }

    }    

    </script>
```

---

```
<apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioinput" onChange="myFunction(this);">
                        <apex:selectOption itemlabel="CPF" itemValue="CPF" />   
                        <apex:selectOption itemlabel="CNPJ" itemValue="CNPJ"/> 
                    </apex:selectRadio>     

                <td><apex:inputField style="display:none" id="CPF" value="{!Cliente__c.CPF__c}"/></td>                    
                <td><apex:inputField style="display:none" id="CNPJ" value="{!Cliente__c.CNPJ__c}"/></td>
```

I want, when I click on cpf, hide cnpj and remove the true request, and the reverse as well. But the function is not working :(

Comment: Hi Joanes, welcome to SFSE. Can you [edit] your question to be clear about what help you need? It looks like you've written the code; if you're having a specific problem or error, please describe it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript simply isn't going to work here. Even if you got as far as showing/hiding the fields, the net result would be that you'd get errors when interacting with the controller.

However, while we're on that topic, your JS has two main problems. First, ID values on apex namespace components are "mangled" by the system, so you need to use [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm) variable, and second, JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, so it would have been `V.value`, not `V.Value`.

The Visualforce way of doing this would be to use apex:actionSupport:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
  <apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioinput" value="{!typeSelection}">
    <apex:selectOption itemlabel="CPF" itemValue="CPF" />
    <apex:selectOption itemlabel="CNPJ" itemValue="CNPJ"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="CPF,CNPJ" />
  </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!typeSelection='CPF'}" id="CPF">
  <td><apex:inputField required="true" value="{!Cliente__c.CPF__c}"/></td>                    
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!typeSelection='CPNJ'}" id="CNPJ">
  <td><apex:inputField required="true" value="{!Cliente__c.CNPJ__c}"/></td>  
</apex:outputText>
```

Additional tweaks may be necessary, but this should get you started.

Comment: this error appeared -> Unknown property 'Cliente__cStandardController.typeSelection'



how would I do in the code the use of  $Component variable?

Comment: @JoanesCavalcanti You need an extension/controller to store the data to.

Comment: I understood, I did this exercise last year, but it was a simpler way. I think it was hide and show the div, I just used javascript function. Could I do this using just the javascript?

I'm starting a short time ago :)

Comment: @JoanesCavalcanti You can do it in all HTML/JS, or you can do it in Visualforce. You can't mix them this way because it will cause errors the user will be unable to resolve. `display:none` won't make the field not required, and setting/clearing the required attribute won't affect its Visualforce behavior. It is non-trivial to mix the two techniques.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. thanks!!!